# Is $\sum ^ \infty _{j=0} \psi_j <\ \infty $ a correct use of notation?

Tags: statistics, notation, time-series

In my Statistics class we commonly use '$\sum ^ \infty _{j=0} \psi_j <\ \infty $' to mean a sequence whose sum does not blow up to infinity. 
This annoys me a bit. Maybe because there is a $\infty$ thrown haphazardly.

My question is whether this is truly correct use of notation or one of those cases where you need to close one eye. 
Furthermore, if this is a problem, then shouldn't $x \in [0,\infty)$ also be a problem?

Comment: It is just another way of saying that the sum is finite or that x is finite. It is not ambiguous, which is the main thing.

Comment: If $\psi_j \geq 0$ for all $j$, this is perfectly fine. If the $\psi_j$ can also be negative, it would be a bit of an unusual notation to indicate that the series converges.